# Changing extended ListView to Custom ListView

Tags: android, android-listview

My `MainActivity` extends `ListActivity`, but now I want to add an `ActionBar` and this `Activity` should extend `ActionBarActivity`, to do that I need to change extended `ListView` to a custom `ListView`. I've tried many times, but unsuccessful. How can I do it?

Here's part of my MainActivity Code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
.
.
.
// Hashmap for ListView
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> testList;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    testList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        ListView lv = getListView(); 
}

@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        // Dismiss the progress dialog
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();

    /**
        * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
        * */
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                MainActivity.this, testList,
                R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_NAME, TAG_DESCRICAO }, new int[] { R.id.name,
                R.id.descricao });

        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }   

}
```

Comment: ListActivity is an Activity with an embeded listview, getlistview returns the listview of the activity if you are not extending listactivity do not expect that method instead use findViewById and locate to a listview widget

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, go ahead and extend ActionBarActivity. Then, define your ListView in a layout file. For example, your layout will look something like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/lv_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        </ListView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Now, in your activity, you set the content view to the layout we created above. Next, get a reference to the ListView with findViewById. Finally, bind your adapter to the ListView. By the way, an [ArrayAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html) may suit you better.

Code:

```
public class ListTestActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    ListView mListView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_test);
        mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_list);
        mListView.setAdapter(new SimpleAdapter(
            MainActivity.this, testList,
            R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_NAME, TAG_DESCRICAO }, new int[] { R.id.name,
            R.id.descricao });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try including super.onCreate(savedInstanceState) prior to everything else you have within the onCreate.

Comment: Ok. But it's not the problem. When I change "extends ListActivity" to "extends ActionBarActivity" this line "ListView lv = getListView(); " don't work.